# Create N duplicates of row based on variable + one extra column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe`

```
structure(list(Phial serial = c("NC09082157761", "NC10082157882B", 
"NC10082157882C", "NC10082157882D", "NC10082157882A", "NC11082157883B", 
"NC11082157883A", "NC11082157883C", "NC11082157883D", "NC11082157883E", 
"NC11082157883G", "NC11082157883F", "NC13082157855A", "NC16082157886A", 
"NC17082157947B", "NC17082157947C", "NC17082157947A", "NC18082157948B", 
"NC18082157948C", "NC18082157948D", "NC18082157948A", "NC18082157948E", 
"NC18082157948F", "NC18082157948G", "NC18082157948H", "NC19082157949A", 
"NC20082157950A", "NC20082157950B", "NC20082157950C"), `Creation date` = structure(c(1628467200, 
1628553600, 1628553600, 1628553600, 1628553600, 1628640000, 1628640000, 
1628640000, 1628640000, 1628640000, 1628640000, 1628640000, 1628812800, 
1629072000, 1629158400, 1629158400, 1629158400, 1629244800, 1629244800, 
1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 
1629331200, 1629417600, 1629417600, 1629417600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Creation time = c(730, 845, 845, 
845, 845, 730, 730, 730, 730, 730, 730, 730, 845, 730, 845, 845, 
845, 845, 845, 845, 845, 845, 845, 845, 845, 715, 730, 730, 730
), Isotope = c("TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", 
"TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", 
"TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", 
"TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", "TL201", 
"TL201", "TL201"), Chemical = c("CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", 
"CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", 
"CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", "CL", 
"CL", "CL"), Init activity = c(147, 145, 144, 146, 144, 147, 
147, 147, 147, 141, 141, 141, 229, 147, 144, 145, 143, 144, 144, 
144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 231, 231, 231, 231), Init volume = c(2, 
2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 
2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Dispose date = structure(c(1629072000, 
1629072000, 1629072000, 1629072000, 1629072000, NA, 1629244800, 
1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 
1629244800, 1629244800, 1629244800, 1629417600, NA, NA, NA, 1629417600, 
1629417600, 1629417600, 1629417600, 1629244800, NA, NA, NA, NA
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Dispose time = c(1624, 
1622, 1622, 1623, 1622, NA, 1535, 1535, 1536, 1536, 1536, 1536, 
1534, 1204, 1533, 1533, 1440, NA, NA, NA, 1441, 1442, 1443, 1443, 
1532, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This details when radioactive stock is present in the building. Each `Phial serial` is delivered on `df$Creation date` and is removed on `df$Disposal date`. I create a new field `Days in Stock`

#To deal with phials not yet disposed (i.e NAs)

```
df$`Dispose date`[is.na(df$`Dispose date`)] <- end_date
```

#Same for times

```
df$`Dispose time`[is.na(df$`Dispose time`)] <- 1700
```

```
df$Days in Stock = as.Date(df$Dispose date) - as.Date(df$Creation date) + 1
```

Now I would like to create "quasi-duplicates" of each row in `df` based on the field `Days in Stock` which is easy enough:

```
df[rep(row.names(df), df$Days in Stock),1:9]
```

However, I would like to create one extra column in the duplicated data.frame `Date`. For each row in the duplicate `Date` should increment from `Creation Date` to `Disposal Date`. I'm not sure how I can do this with the above duplication step.

---

For example row 1 in the `df`

```
Phial serial  Creation date  Creation time  Isotope  Chemical  Init activity
Init volume  Dispose date  Dispose time
NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
```

Should transform to

```
Date  Phial serial  Creation date  Creation time  Isotope  Chemical  Init activity
    Init volume  Dispose date  Dispose time
2021-08-09  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-10  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-11  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-12  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-13  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-14  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-15  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
2021-08-16  NC09082157761  2021-08-09  730  TL201  CL  147  2.0  2021-08-16  1624
```

Comment: @RonakShah have edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `tidyverse` answer.

I have replaced `NA` in `Dispose date` with `Creation date` and for each row create a sequence of Dates from `Creation date`  to `Dispose date` and store it in a list which can be unlisted in separate rows using `unnest`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(days_in_stock = as.Date(`Dispose date`) - as.Date(`Creation date`) + 1, 
         `Dispose date` = coalesce(`Dispose date`, `Creation date`), 
         Date = map2(as.Date(`Creation date`), as.Date(`Dispose date`), seq, by = '1 day')) %>%
  unnest(Date)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much